# How to solve the Error related to Python Libraries on no module?

Tags: python, batch-file, deep-diff

I am using Python lib deepdiff.

I Installed using cmd -> python -m pip install --trusted-host https://pypi.python.org deepdiff as I got an error with SSL I used above to cmd. When I worked in pycharm using python version35 and executed my file.

```
  C:\Python35\python.exe C:/Users/mytry.py
   {'values_changed': {"r"}}
 It works in Pycharm Tools
```

But when I try to run the file mytry.py in cmd prompt I get =>

```
from deepdiff import DeepDiff
ImportError: No module named deepdiff
```

I m using 3.5.4 in local as well 
I don't know how to solve this please help!!

Comment: does pip freeze show deepdiff as one of the packages installed ?

Comment: How do you run it in the command prompt?

Comment: @dow Are you sure that uses the same python installation as calling `c:\python35\python.exe`? Maybe you have another python installed and it is found first on the path when the command prompt searches for something matching `python`. What is the value of `PATH`? Call `set path` in the prompt  to see its setting.

Comment: Yes, I have two versions python 27 and python 35 but in env variables, is pointed to 35 only. and in cmd when i type python in cmd it shows 
Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:07:06) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32  and wen i did set path it shows 
;C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages;C:\Python35;C:\Python35\Scripts

Comment: C:\Python35\python.exe myfile.py -- > it works Thanks all it worked now but i think using 2 versions is the problem. is there any solution to do without C:\Python35\python.exe

Comment: What is the full value of `set path`? Edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after using the version in the command prompt.

```
 C:\Python35\python.exe  myfile.py
 Output: BOTH JSON Match
```

Thanks all for your help.